# custom External Payment Gateway - WebHook to handle the response without user visit

Tags: payment-gateway, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I've followed the skeleton of [GitHub](https://github.com/PrestaShop/paymentexample/blob/master/paymentexample.php) and read the official [documentation](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/modules/payment/) about payments. I'm relating to the "external" example, where the user is redirected to an external service, makes the payment, and then the gateway notifies the result. Anyway I don't get how to properly handle the response.

The example redirects the user to a page (validation.php) that, once opened, closes the order.
But what if the user close the page before loading it? Or if the user is not logged-in anymore?
I'd rather to send a trigger from the gateway-server to Prestashop, without the interaction of the user.
But I don't know how to do that.

The gateway service already has 2 params: one for the user redirection, one for the cient webhook to trigger. But I don't know this last one.

This is the main .php file of the module, where I list my custom gateway, and then call external.php if the user chooses this payment method.

```php
    private function getExternalPaymentOption($cart)
    {
        $externalOption = new PaymentOption();
        $externalOption->setModuleName($this->name);
        $externalOption->setAction($this->context->link->getModuleLink($this->name, 'external', [], true));
        return $externalOption;
    }
```

This below is `external.php`, that redirects the user to the external gateway. In the call, the `redirect_ok` is user redirection in case of success, that url is the validation.php page. Anyway I don't know what to insert as webhook_ok: the webhook to trigger in case of success.

```php
 public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        // take the cart to pass to the external gateway
        $cart = $this->context->cart;

        // prepare the redirect url on success
        $ok_redirect = $this->context->link->getModuleLink(
                                                           $this->module->name,     
                                                            'validation', 
                                                            [],
                                                            true
                                                           );
         // === I DON'T KNOW WHAT INSERT HERE =====
         $ok_webhook = "???????????";
         // =======================================

         // call the external gateway
         $ch = curl_init("https://external-gatway.com");
         $payload = [
                     cart        => $cart,
                     redirect_ok => $ok_redirect,
                     webhook_ok  => $ok_webhook
                    ];
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        // the response has the url to be opened by the user
        $response = json_decode($response, true);  
 
        //redirect the user to that url
        Tools::redirect($response['data']['url']);       
    }
```

Once the user makes the payment, it will be redirected to $ok_redirect, that is the `validation.php` page.

```php
    public function postProcess()
    {
        $customer = new Customer($this->context->cart->id_customer);

        // transform the cart in order
        $this->module->validateOrder(
             (int) $this->context->cart->id,
             (int) $this->getOrderState(),
             (float) $this->context->cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH),
             $this->module->displayName,  // $this->getOptionName(),
             null,
             [],
             (int) $this->context->currency->id,
             false,
             $customer->secure_key
         );

        // redirect to the order confirmation page
        Tools::redirect($this->context->link->getPageLink(
            'order-confirmation',
            true,
            (int) $this->context->language->id,
            [
                'id_cart' => (int) $this->context->cart->id,
                'id_module' => (int) $this->module->id,
                'id_order' => (int) $this->module->currentOrder,
                'key' => $customer->secure_key,
            ]
        ));
    }
```

This last step works, but just if the user visit that page, and he is logged. I need to replicate this step just as Server-To-Server without the user visit.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating 2 controllers, very similar but one has not checks on logged user:

- `validation` checks context, current user, current cart;
- `webhook`    checks a custom header for the server gateway signature. No user logged needed.

Both of them close the order setting the status as 'paid'.
Since 'webhook' can't take data from context, I retrieve them from the DB.

So steps are:

1. prepare redirect_url

```php
$ok_redirect = $this->context->link->getModuleLink($this->module->name, 'validation', [], true);
```

2. prepare webooh_url

```php
$ok_webhook = $this->context->link->getModuleLink($this->module->name,  'webhookok',  [], true);
```

3. make the request to the payment gateway, passing `$ok_redirect` and `$ok_webhook`;
4. get the `payment_id` together to the `checkout_url` where to redirect the user to start the checkout process;
5. save in DB needed data (customer_id, cart_id, customer_safe_key, cart_total) with `payment_id` as primary key;
6. redirect the user to `checkout_url`;
7. once completed, the gateway triggers the 'webhookok', passing the `payment_id`;
8. retrieve all the data from the DB and close the order as 'paid'.